# Apache Passenger + Rails + assets are not getting reflected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am running rails application on Apache Passenger in development environment.
I wanted to add some css and javascript libraries in application.
So i added css in application.css, and javascript in application.js files.

Assets are not getting loaded.

I have also precompiled the assets by running -
rake assets:precompile
and then i restarted the server.

Is there anything which i am missing?

Comment: Have you set Apache to serve the public folder of the Rails application?
In Production mode by default Rails will not serve it's own assets.

Comment: try using exec command and also have a look on following link : https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/dev/ruby/rails_integration.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try 
bundle exec rake assets:clean

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

and then restart your server

**Note:** Please do a cross check in your application.css that you are requiring that file if not then add
*= require your_file_name.css